# disabled checked checkbox is not being sent to model on form submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with checkboxes that are automatically checked & disabled based on on a users selection using jquery. However, when I submit the form, the checked boxes value does not get sent to the model. If I remove the jquery code and check the boxes manually then the data is sent correctly to the model and everything works. This is the jquery code I have been using. I have also tried using

```
 $('.verification5').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('.verification5').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

.prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: If it is disabled it is not read/found as checked.  On your form submit you can enable them on submit then the value/check will be grabbed

Comment: thank you! this answered my question as to why it wasn't sending!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On form submit you need to enable checkbox first

```
$(form).submit(){
         $('.verification5').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Or instead of using disabled property you can also use readonly property as readOnly property can be sent to server on form submit.

Comment: this is the solution I ultimately ended up with so that the users cant edit the checkbox. and still send the data. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Input fields with disabled attribute does not send their value to the controller while submitting the form. You can use one of below solution to overcome the issue

1) You can use **readonly** attribute instead of **disabled** attribute to send data to controller

2) You can add **hidden field** for the **disabled** checkbox property to send data to controller

Answer (score 0):

Each element that is disabled, semantically it means that does not have any behaviour. So, it will not be send to the server. You can see on the specification of this section of the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-readonly-attribute).

You can change the `disable` to `readonly` and it is a valid information but only for read propose. It will be send and not changed. For sample:

```
$('.verification5').prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: I am trying this, but how can I keep the checkbox disabled, or not editable the readonly property isnt really keep the user from unselecting the checkbox